# Moving block to left side

Tags: magento2, layout, sidebar

I got this block:

> \Magento\Sales\Block\Reorder\Sidebar

On page it is within the div `sidebar-additional` which is located on the right side.
However I want the sidebar to be located on the left side.

Here it is being set:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Reorder\Sidebar" name="sale.reorder.sidebar" as="reorder" template="reorder/sidebar.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: What is your template for that page? 1-column, 2-columns-left or something else?

Comment: My template for it seems to be default.xml

Comment: default.xml is not a template. Its a layout file. I need to know the page layout.

Comment: I don't know it. That is the problem.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the full page where it shows on right?

Comment: maybe you mean this: module-sales/view/frontend/templates/reorder/sidebar.phtml

Comment: No this is the template file for reorder siderbar but I need to know the page layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77850/discussion-between-l-klmn-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: Could you please share with me your me website url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See set page layout & rearrange elements.
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

Comment: Which xml would be the right for me? Thanks!

Comment: @L.Klmn which main page layout are you using that you are attempting to adjust? Be sure to use the 3 or 2 column layout page.xml that Sukumar Gorai mentioned in comments above. Without the proper page.xml layout specified you may only have 1 column or 2 columns preventing the move. Also specifically https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange